# I get the message: "The pexpect python module is required" when running pexpect module on ansible

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x, pexpect

I am very new to ansible and I am trying to run a playbook to change root password of hosts so I am using the expect command of pexpect module. 
I successfully managed to install pexpect v4.7 with python 2.7 on the hosts and on the local server running the playbook.
However when the playbook is being run, it fails with error: "The pexpect python module is required"

According to the requirements, pexpect and python are of the correct version

```
Files installed on hosts for pexpect and python: 
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.7.0-py2.7.egg-info
/usr/pexpect-4.7.0
/usr/pexpect-4.7.0/doc/api/pexpect.rst
/usr/pexpect-4.7.0/pexpect.egg-info
/usr/pexpect-4.7.0/tests/pexpectTest.py
/usr/pexpect-4.7.0/pexpect
/usr/pexpect-4.7.0/build/lib/pexpect
```

The playbook is as follows:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: change password for root user
      expect: 
        command: passwd root
        responses: 
           (?i)password: "password"
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help!

Comment: Do you have any more information or code? Perhaps I am ignorant of playbook but would love to try and help.

Comment: @AnthonySette I highly appreciate it, tell me what more info are you looking for?

Comment: Do you have any code? Just wanted to see how you were importing it.

Comment: @AnthonySette That's all the code I have. Should there be any more code?

Comment: Just did a bit of research, I don't think I understand playbook well enough to help you out. I was expecting some sort of python code but playbook is very different haha. Wish I could help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by removing pexpect from all hosts then installing epel-release, pip and pexpect packages accordingly.